# Jinja - Why is my macro not working as expected?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have 34 tables, each containing the column "UUID" and I'm trying to append all the uuids to 1 table.

I wrote the following macro that should create a list of all tables in schema "test_logs" that their names end with the suffix "_semc":

```
{% macro list_tables(schema_name, tables_suffix) %}
  {% set matching_tables = [] %}

  {% for table in run_query("select lower(table_name) as table_name from information_schema.tables WHERE lower(table_schema) = '" ~ schema_name ~ "' AND lower(table_name) LIKE '%" ~ tables_suffix ~ "'") %}
    {% do matching_tables.append(table[0]) %}
  {% endfor %}

 {{ matching_tables}}
{% endmacro %}
```

I then try to do a UNION that will append all the uuids from each table to a single table:

```
{{ config(materialized='table', schema='dwh')}}

{%set test_logsi = select list_tables('test_logs', '_semc') %}

{% for table_name in test_logsi %}
  SELECT uuid FROM research_db.test_logs.table_name
  {% if not loop.last %} UNION {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason it's not working and I'm getting the following:

```
SELECT uuid FROM research_db.test_logs.table_name
   UNION 

  SELECT uuid FROM research_db.test_logs.table_name
   UNION 

  SELECT uuid FROM research_db.test_logs.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The matching tables can be returned from the function "list_tables" by getting values of the query result.

```
{% macro list_tables(schema_name, tables_suffix) %}
  {% set query %}
  select lower(table_name) as table_name from `dbt-bigquery`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  where lower(table_schema) = '{{ schema_name }}'
  and lower(table_name) like '%{{ tables_suffix }}'
  {% endset %}
  {% set results = run_query(query) %}
  {% if execute %}
    {% set matching_tables = results.columns[0].values() %}
  {% else %}
    {% set matching_tables = [] %}
  {% endif %}
  {% do log(matching_tables, info=true) %}
  {{ return(matching_tables) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

In the uuid union, to reference the table-name variable, you need to enclose it with double curly braces.

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

{% set test_logsi = list_tables('test_logs', '_semc') %}
{% do log(test_logsi, info=true) %}
{% for table_name in test_logsi -%}
select uuid from `dbt-bigquery.test_logs.{{ table_name }}`
{% if not loop.last %}union all{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you can skip the spaces by trying to add "-" before or after %.
https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/jinja/jinja-whitespace